# HowTo Generate List of SQL Server Jobs and their owners

Tags: sql-server

How would I go about generating a list of sql jobs and their owners? I would also like to be able to generate this list for SSIS packages also.

Thanks

Answer (score 75, accepted):

try this

**Jobs**

```
select s.name,l.name
 from  msdb..sysjobs s 
 left join master.sys.syslogins l on s.owner_sid = l.sid
```

**Packages**

```
select s.name,l.name 
from msdb..sysssispackages s 
 left join master.sys.syslogins l on s.ownersid = l.sid
```

Comment: Thank You! The top one works... but the bottom one gives me an invalid object name error 'msdb..sysssispackages'... Do I not have something installed that I should for the SSIS stuff?

Comment: on sql 2005 you need to use sysdtspackages90, that got changed with sysssispackages  in 2008, see also http://wiki.lessthandot.com/index.php/List_all_SSIS_packages_and_the_owner_of_those_SSIS_packages

Comment: Scenario: previous DBA set job under her ownership, left, login removed from server, above shows NULL for that job's owner. Use buckley's query with SUSER_SNAME.

Comment: Thx, based on your answer I was able to find the DPM jobs that were failing:
select s.name as 'Job_Name',l.name as 'Owner_Account'
from  msdb..sysjobs s 
 left join master.sys.syslogins l on s.owner_sid = l.sid WHERE s.enabled=1

Answer (score 49):

It's better to use SUSER_SNAME() since when there is no corresponding login on the server the join to syslogins will not match

```
SELECT  s.name ,
        SUSER_SNAME(s.owner_sid) AS owner
FROM    msdb..sysjobs s 
ORDER BY name
```

Comment: This deserves more ups; it's a very helpful addition to the first answer because it shows you owner-names even if they're not associated with a server-login.  Thanks!

Answer (score 15):

A colleague told me about this stored procedure...

USE msdb

EXEC dbo.sp_help_job

Answer (score 4):

If you don't have access to sysjobs table (someone elses server etc) you might be have or be allowed access to sysjobs_view

```
SELECT *
 from  msdb..sysjobs_view s 
 left join master.sys.syslogins l on s.owner_sid = l.sid
```

or

```
SELECT *, SUSER_SNAME(s.owner_sid) AS owner
 from  msdb..sysjobs_view s
```

Answer (score 1):

There is an easy way to get Jobs' Owners info from multiple instances by PowerShell:

Run the script in your PowerShell ISE:

**Loads SQL Powerhell SMO and commands:**

```
Import-Module SQLPS -disablenamechecking
```

**BUild list of Servers manually (this builds an array list):**

```
$SQLServers = "SERVERNAME\INSTANCE01","SERVERNAME\INSTANCE02","SERVERNAME\INSTANCE03";
$SysAdmins = $null;
foreach($SQLSvr in $SQLServers)
{
    ## - Add Code block:
    $MySQL = new-object Microsoft.SqlServer.Management.Smo.Server $SQLSvr;
    DIR SQLSERVER:\SQL\$SQLSvr\JobServer\Jobs| FT $SQLSvr, NAME, OWNERLOGINNAME -Auto 
    ## - End of Code block
}
```

Comment: If you are having trouble with a separate problem ("_But is there anybody help me to generate an excel report?_") - [ask a new question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) - it is the best way to get a response, and more people will actually see it :) Good luck